# Bloom filter creating different arrays from two input sets

Tags: probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, bloom-filters

Assume a **bloom filter** that is composed of $H = \{H_1, ..., H_k\}$ hash functions, and uniformly maps elements from an input set $X$ to an array $A$ of size $n$. Let $X_1, X_2$ (not same) be two input sets of size $m$. After applying the same bloom filter to both input sets, we receive the arrays $A_1$ and $A_2$ (both of size $n$). What is the probability that the arrays differ?

Here is what I have figured out so far:

- Prob that any bit $b_i$ (from any of the arrays) is not set is: $P[b_i = 0] = (1-1/n)^{km}$
- Thus, prob that any bit $b_i$ is set is: $P[b_i=1] = 1 - (1-1/n)^{km}$
- Prob that for the two arrays the bit at position $i$ (let's call them $b$ and $b*$) is different equals the probability that only one of the two is set: $P[b=0 \cap b*=1] = (1-1/n)^{km}(1-(1-1/n)^{km}) $ **(here I am not sure whether I also have to include the opposite case and subtract the prob that both events occur as they are independent)**
- So, the prob that this is true for all $n$ positions of the arrays is: $P=[b=0 \cap b*=1] = ((1-1/n)^{km}(1-(1-1/n)^{km}))^n$

Any inputs would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Since you’re doing m insertions, shouldn’t the probability that b_i=0 be $(1-1/n)^{km}$?

Comment: @AshwinGanesan Yes! I updated my question accordingly

Comment: The probability depends on the input sets $X_1, X_2$. In particular, If $X_1 = X_2$ then the arrays are equal with probability $1$. Are there unstated assumptions?

Comment: @pcpthm Forgot to mention that, the input sets $X_1, X_2$ are not assumed to be equal.